# How to check NWAdmin commands required -url as parameters in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Through powershell I want to execute NWAdmin commands. I have written simple command as shown below.

```
$spWebURL = Read-Host "Enter Web Application URL:"
$spWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $spWebURL
$NWAdminCommand = Read-Host "Enter NWAdmin Command to perform request action:"
if(Test-Path(".\NWAdmin.exe"))
{ 
foreach ($SPSite in $spWebApp.Sites)
{
    foreach($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs)
    {
        $SiteURL= $SPWeb.URL;

        $NWAdminCommandTest=".\NWAdmin.exe -o $NWAdminCommand -url $SiteURL";

        iex $NWAdminCommandTest;

    }
}
}
```

NWAdmin commands format is shown below.

```
NWAdmin.exe -o PurgeWorkflowData [-workflowName workflowName] [-state[All|Running|Completed|Cancelled|Error]] [-url teamsiteUrl [-listName listName]] [-deletedLists]
```

How to check if user enter **PurgeWorkflowData** as command, is NWAdmin commands required **-url** as parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand the question at the end but you can check for someone writing `PurgeWorkflowdata` as the command by using `-eq` in the second `ForEach`

Heres some code you can play with

```
$spWebURL = Read-Host "Enter Web Application URL:"
$spWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $spWebURL
$NWAdminCommand = Read-Host "Enter NWAdmin Command to perform request action:"
if(Test-Path(".\NWAdmin.exe"))
{ 
    foreach ($SPSite in $spWebApp.Sites)
    {
        foreach($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs)
        {
            if ($NWAdminCommand -eq 'PurgeWorkflowData')
            {
                Write-Host "User entered the magical command PurgeWorkFlowData <do stuff here>"
            }
            else
            {
                $SiteURL= $SPWeb.URL;

                $NWAdminCommandTest=".\NWAdmin.exe -o $NWAdminCommand -url $SiteURL";

                iex $NWAdminCommandTest;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want user entered command XXX (for example:PurgeWorkFlowData) requires -URL as param.

Comment: I am new to powershell and I want to validate a tricky rule.
Let's assume I enter Get-SPSite as command and it may have required params as well. Assume Identity is required Params for Get-SPSite command.
I want to do programming as shown below scenario.
If(requiredParams.Contains(-Identity))
{
//do stuff
}
else
{
//do stuff
}

Any possibility in powershell?

Comment: The only way i can think of at the moment you could do this is by putting every possible command and their required parameters into an array which can be checked by `if ($RequiredParams -Contains 'Identity')`. I'm currently at work, when i get home if i can get some free time i can look a bit more into this for you and see what i come up with.